# How to align vertical:middle filter icon in Kendo UI Grid Header

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm customizing kendo Grid header styles like in this jsFiddle sample.

[Sample jsFiddle which demonstrates my issue](http://jsfiddle.net/C4KWQ/4/)

```
 $("#test-grid-2").kendoGrid({
  columns: [{
    field: "user.screen_name",
    title: "This is my centered header",
    headerAttributes: { "class": "center-header"},
      filterable:true
  },
           {
    field: "text",
    title: "This is my long header title to test",
    headerAttributes: { "class": "wrap-header"},
               filterable:true,
               width:100
  }],
  dataSource: viewModel.remoteSource,
    filterable:true
});
```

And corresponding CSS:

```
.k-grid-header .center-header {
  text-align: center;
}
.k-grid-header .wrap-header {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

But if I have narrow column width, I get the filter icon not vertically aligned as shown on second column of sample fiddle.

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: Please also provide relevant code in your question and do not try to circumvent the mechanism that blocks you from posting it when there's a link to jsfiddle and no block of code (you deactivated the link in order to do so)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a perfect solution, but I have been working on something in this vein recently.

The basic problem is that the `<a>` containing the filter icon is floated right, which means it's going to want to rise to the top of the parent. If you contrast the two `<th>` elements in Dev Tools, you'll see that because they're vertically middle-aligned the two filter icons are actually at the top right-hand corner of their respective parents.

How to fix?

I don't have a great answer, but what I'm researching now is a possible CSS approach:

```
.k-grid-header .k-header {
    position: relative;
}
.k-header > .k-grid-filter {
    position: absolute;
    float: none;
    top: 35%;
    right: 6px;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/C4KWQ/66/